# What does "boilerplate" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I knew the term "boilerplate" in object oriented programming. It means that the programmers create too many classes for just doing a simple programming task.

But "boilerplate" is also used in other field like this sentence.

> We've tried getting info from friends who work at Facebook, prior
>   representatives we've worked with (we've been advertising on Facebook
>   since 2010 in previous non-dating sites we've built), only to receive
>   the same boilerplate response about approved advertisers.

So what does "boilerplate" in the above sentence mean?

Comment: What part of a dictionary definition of [boilerplate](http://thefreedictionary.com/boilerplate) (3) may not apply to this question?

Comment: @SrJoven: Rather, "4. (Commerce) a draft contract that can easily be modified to cover various types of transaction;" "2 b. trite, hackneyed writing" *ibid.*

Comment: I have never heard "boilerplate" used to mean "create too many classes for just doing a simple programming task". Are you sure you didn't infer the wrong definition from context?

Comment: @Peter, maybe u right but boilerplate has negative meaning

Comment: *"Boilerplate"* could be used to mean "add a standard set of classes to your program", which would be overkill for a simple programming task.

Comment: "Boilerplate" means any sort of "canned" text.  It appears likely that the origin of the term is from the publishing definition where the text was (in ancient times) delivered on a pre-formed "plate", ready to install on a printing press.  The term has taken on an additional (and more negative) meaning to mean the "small print" in contracts and the like -- dense and clearly designed to discourage you from actually reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Boilerplate" means something generic that can be re-used with minimal adaption: like a standard email reply.

(BTW, in software programming it means pretty much the same thing as what I have written above: the (perhaps over-)use of generic code that often clutters the programme where something bespoke would be much leaner and clearer: in other words, "create too many classes for just doing a simple programming task" describes the effect of using too much boilerplate code, rather than defining it).

Comment: so u mean "the same boilerplate response"= "the same generic response" without any difference?

Comment: @Tom -- "The same boilerplate response" would imply that the response appeared to be a standard text that was repeatedly reused.  Back in the days when potential employers actually sent rejection letters, they were famous for being "boilerplate" -- often word-for-word identical between different companies.